# Numpy: what happens with 3D-boolean index array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean

Normally, `numpy` arrays are much faster than list operations or loops, but in this case too?:

I have a 4D-array and a boolean index-array for the first three axis'; the output of the indexing is flattened, at least in the index axis', so its a 'list of tuples' (but in array form).

Since the regular structure is broken, I assume that this is much slower than indexing of a regular grid (i.e. indexing each axis independently) would be? Maybe numpy internally really computes a list of tuples and then converts it to an array?

---

*Why I ask:* I would like to enumerate the output, to be able to compute for any tuple if it is in the list, and on which position. I try to understand which method might be fast and elegant...

*My context:* 
I have an array of integer koordinates, a grid - so logically I have a 3D-Array of 3-tuples, but for the program it's a 4D-Array.

I want to get all points for which the sum of coordinates equals a constant, which is cutting a plane out of my cube (finally, I take two adjacent planes, which gives me a honeycomb lattice -- it's quite pretty if you like math :))

So the values in the last axis are just the indices of the first three axis'. If I had not only an index array of `True` and `False`, but also had assigned an id instead of each `True`, then I could easily read out the id for each tuple.

This might be an elegant and fast way to the task (the goal is to know for each site in one of the planes which sites of the other are adjacent -- so their coordinates are known, but I want their id).

So, does numpy internally do any magic to get the indexed array? Or would it be similarly fast to take a `for-loop` ;) (no, I see by trying, that this is much faster, but why...)

---

Some code (comments in German, sorry)

```
import numpy as np
Seitenlaenge = 4
kArray = np.zeros((Seitenlaenge, Seitenlaenge, Seitenlaenge, 3)) # 4D-Array, hier soll dann an der Stelle [x, y, z, :] der Vektor (x, y, z) stehen
kArray[:, :, :, 2] = np.arange(Seitenlaenge).reshape((1, 1, Seitenlaenge)).repeat(Seitenlaenge, axis = 0).repeat(Seitenlaenge, axis = 1)
kArray[:, :, :, 1] = np.arange(Seitenlaenge).reshape((1, Seitenlaenge, 1)).repeat(Seitenlaenge, axis = 0).repeat(Seitenlaenge, axis = 2)
kArray[:, :, :, 0] = np.arange(Seitenlaenge).reshape((Seitenlaenge, 1, 1)).repeat(Seitenlaenge, axis = 1).repeat(Seitenlaenge, axis = 2)
# Die Gitterpunkte waehlen die zu A und B gehoeren:

print kArray

Summe = 5 # Seitenlaenge des Dreiecks, das aus dem 1.Oktanten geschnitten wuerde, wenn der Wuerfel nicht kleiner waere
ObA = kArray.sum(axis=-1) == Summe-1 # 3D-boolean Array
ObB = kArray.sum(axis=-1) == Summe-2

print ObA

kA, kB = kArray[ObA], kArray[ObB] # Es bleiben 2D-Arrays: Listen von Koordina-
# tentripeln, in der Form (x, y, z)

print kA
```

and if you like to see the honeycomb lattice, then do afterwards:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nx = np.array([-1, 1, 0])*2**-0.5
ny = np.array([-1, -1, 2])*6**-0.5
def Projektion(ListeTripel):
    return dot(ListeTripel, nx), dot(ListeTripel, ny)

xA, yA = Projektion(kA)
xB, yB = Projektion(kB)

plt.plot(xA.flatten(), yA.flatten(), 'o', c='r', ms=8, mew=0)
plt.plot(xB.flatten(), yB.flatten(), 'o', c='b', ms=8, mew=0)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Post some sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy is pretty smart about indexing. It will flatten your boolean array, compute `nnz`, the number of `True`s in it, allocate an output array of shape `(nnz, 3)`, then iterate simultaneously over your flattened boolean array item by item, and your flattened array in jumps of 3 items, i.e. with a 3 item *stride*. Wherever the boolean array has a `True` it will copy the next 3 items of your array to the output array, then continue with the iteration.

All of this will happen in C, so it is very, very fast, at least by Python standards.

By the way, somewhat unrelated to your question, but use [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
length = 4
indices = np.arange(length)
k_array = np.empty((length,) * 3 + (3,), dtype=np.intp)
k_array[..., 0] = indices
k_array[... ,1] = indices[:, None]
k_array[... ,2] = indices[:, None, None]
```

Comment: This makes sense! :) Thank you for your explanation and also for the hint about the broadcasting, this looks neater, of course. 
I saw such arrays with `None` already, but I thought 'explicit is better than implicit' ;-) - I'll try to read and understand it, thanks.

Comment: I think that last 1 should be a 2. Also, TIL about `np.intp` as an equivalent to `size_t`